# How to make a numerical series with specific increment using python?

Tags: python, list, series

I want to create this series using python:

```
[0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2, 0.23, ......, 0.97, 1, .... 1.97, 2]
```

From 0 to 1, there must be 30 data points, and so on.
So, the pattern is +0.03 +0.04 +0.03 +0.03

Is there a built-in function for creating this kind of series? or what would the best algorithm be?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourSeries = [round(x/30,2) for x in range(0,61)]
```

...might be what you're after.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I'VE BEEN WANDERING FOR HOURS JUST TO SOLVE THIS :'')) I'm a beginner in programming hehe. anyway really thank you so much!! you made my day :')) I wish you always stay safe and healthy <3

Comment: @nidzytryingtocode if is the solution to you question validate it

Comment: @nidzytryingtocode That's called a list comprehension. They can be very handy! And what Enrique said.